# reversing two's complement for 18bit int

Tags: c++, twos-complement

I have an 18 bit integer that is in two's complement and I'd like to convert it to a signed number so I can better use it. On the platform I'm using, ints are 4 bytes (i.e. 32 bits). Based on this post:

[Convert Raw 14 bit Two's Complement to Signed 16 bit Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075922/convert-raw-14-bit-twos-complement-to-signed-16-bit-integer)

I tried the following to convert the number:

```
using SomeType = uint64_t;
SomeType largeNum = 0x32020e6ed2006400;
int twosCompNum = (largeNum & 0x3FFFF);
int regularNum = (int) ((twosCompNum << 14) / 8192);
```

I shifted the number left 14 places to get the sign bit as the most significant bit and then divided by 8192 (in binary, it's 1 followed by 13 zeroes) to restore the magnitude (as mentioned in the post above). However, this doesn't seem to work for me. As an example, inputting 249344 gives me -25600, which prima facie doesn't seem correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type is `twosCompNum`?

Comment: twosCompNum is an int, but it is the lower 18 bits of a uint64_t.

Comment: Split those operations into their own lines of code. Step through with a debugger. Should be pretty obvious what's going on.

Comment: You could also use bitwise operations to observe the sign bit and rebuild your number.

Comment: 249344 is too large for an 18-bit 2s complement integer, which can only be in the range -131072 .. 131071.

Comment: you need to shift right 14 bits to do a sign extension `(twosCompNum << 14) >> 14`. Divide by 8192 won't work since it'll round toward zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The almost-portable way (with assumption that negative integers are natively 2s-complement) is to simply inspect bit 17, and use that to conditionally mask in the sign bits:

```
constexpr SomeType sign_bits = ~SomeType{} << 18;
int regularNum = twosCompNum & 1<<17 ? twosCompNum | sign_bits : twosCompNum;
```

Note that this doesn't depend on the size of your `int` type.

Answer (score 1):

The constant `8192` is wrong, it should be `16384 = (1<<14)`.

```
int regularNum = (twosCompNum << 14) / (1<<14);
```

With this, the answer is correct, `-12800`.

It is correct, because the input (unsigned) number is 249344 (0x3CE00). It has its highest bit set, so it is a negative number. We can calculate its signed value by subtracting "max unsigned value+1" from it: `0x3CE00-0x40000=-12800`.

Note, that if you are on a platform, for which right signed shift does the right thing (like on x86), then you can avoid division:

```
int regularNum = (twosCompNum << 14) >> 14;
```

This version can be slightly faster (but has implementation-defined behavior), if the compiler doesn't notice that division can be exactly replaced by a shift (clang 7 notices, but gcc 8 doesn't).

Comment: *For negative `a`, the value of `a >> b` is implementation-defined*, so be careful to read the specification of every compiler you want to use that with.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: first your test input is not an 18-bit two's complement number. With `n` bits, two's compliment permits `-(2 ^ (n - 1)) <= value < 2 ^ (n - 1)`. In the case of 18 bits, that's `-131072 <= value < 131071`. You say you input `249344` which is outside of this range and would actually be interpreted as `-12800`.

The second problem is that your powers of two are off. In the answer you cite, the solution offered is of the form

```
mBitOutput = (mBitCast)(nBitInput << (m - n)) / (1 << (m - n));
```

For your particular problem, you desire

```
int output = (nBitInput << (32 - 18)) / (1 << (32 - 18));
// or equivalent
int output = (nBitInput << 14) / 16384;
```

Try this out.

Comment: divide by 16384 won't work. You always need a arithmetic right shift to do sign extension because division will round toward zero. For example -5/2 = -2 but -5 >> 1 = -3

Comment: @phuclv: it will, because division result doesn't need rounding.

Comment: @geza no. You always need rounding, whether to zero, inf nearest or whatever. And the C++ standard mandates that the result is round to zero. But the arithmetic right shift will round toward negative inf which will make the results differ

Comment: @phuclv: I mean, the division result have zero remainder.

Comment: @geza I got it. Because you've done a left shift so the low 14 bits will be zero. But the [compilers don't realized that and you'll still get worse assembly output](https://godbolt.org/g/vwvX8F) if you use a division

Comment: @phuclv: but clang recognizes :)